# Karma+Jasmine function that reads a json file always fails

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

### I'm having a hard time understanding how unit testing with Karma+Jasmine works exactly

I'm trying to setup some Unit Tests for my AngularJS app but I'm running into a problem where the Tests don't seem to run a function properly.

I have a function that reads a json file through a $http.get request and populates an array, but when I set up in my unit test to expect the length of the array  `expect(array.length).toBe(10)`, it always fails, yet that is the length of the array when I run the App normally. Actually if I print the length in the `console.log` on the unit test it seems to always be stuck at 1.

But for example if I check some of the variables I declare manually then the expect function works properly.

Can anyone tell me what exactly am I missing here? It's seems i'm missing some of the fundamentals on how unit testing with Karma/Jasmine works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that $http.get is an asynchronous method. Unless you sepcifically tell angularjs that it needs to flush that response, it will not. The method will exit and the callback of $http.get will not happen in time for your it method to utilize its $scope transformations.

You can achieve this by expecting the call to happen with the $httpBackend API [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend](http://httpBackend%20docs)

You can then do

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('../json/apps.json').respond(200, {mock: 'api response');
$scope.getAllApps();
$httpBackend.flush();
expect(scope.allApps.length).toBe(10);
```

In your unit tests you should never rely on the actual response of http calls. To ensure you are testing only the method you should always mock the response of what your API is supposed to return.

Comment: I get it, thank you for the explanation. I'm going to be testing out the $httpBackend method now!

Comment: OK so I've been trying to go through the httpBackend method like you said but it just throws an "Error: Unexpected request: GET ../json/apps.json", I even tried to put the json file to match the path the error describes but it still gives the same error.

Comment: After googling a bit I ended up going with the $httpBackend.when('GET', '../../json/apps.json').respond(response); method and that worked out for me. Many thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> $scope.getAllApps = function(){
>     $scope.isLoading = true;
>     $http.get('../json/apps.json').then(function (data){
>         // ...
>     });
>     $scope.isLoading = false;
> };
> ```

BETTER

```
$scope.getAllApps = function(){
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    $http.get('../json/apps.json').then(function (data){
        // ...
    }).finally(function() {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    });
};
```

Because the `$http` service in non-blocking and asynchronous, it immediately returns a promise. It does not wait for data to return from the server. The `isLoading` flag needs to wait for the promise to resolve before setting the flag `false`.

Comment: That's a very good point that I didn't consider. Thank you for the headsup on that one :)